# What is the time complexity of executing a simple query in terms of the number of rows in a table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'd like to know if the time taken to query from a table increases linearly with the number of rows in the table. In short, will the following query

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
```

take 10 times longer to run on average if the table has 10 times as many rows?

I think there are many factors that affect the speed of the query (like sharding of tables), but I'd like to know if on average we can expect it to be linear or perhaps sub-linear.

I tried running queries on different tables of different sizes and ended up with results that suggest it is sub-linear in time. But I'd like to make sure.

Comment: It depends on a large number of factors, some generic, some probably specific to your DBMS e.g. there's an overhead for your DBMS to analyse/prepare the query that is probably independent of the table size; the network returning the data from the DBMS to your UI will have an influence; etc.

Comment: Hi @Deddy, can  you clarify your requirement?

Comment: @ShipraSarkar Nothing specific. Mostly just curious how the underlying algorithm works.

Comment: @NickW I see. So I guess there is no simple answer then.

Comment: Hi @Deddy, The time complexity depends on many factors. Mostly the time taken varies on partitioning of table or data skewness etc. More number of rows will take more time to run select *.  Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @ShipraSarkar thanks for the response. I was hoping for a simple answer like O(n) complexity or something like that, but I guess there are just too many factors in play here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity depends on many factors. It is not limited to any single factor.Mostly the time taken varies on partitioning of table or data skewness etc. More number of rows will take more time to run select *. Since there are too many factors involved, representing in Big O notation is difficult.